# How to remove spaces from output but retain those that are dictionary values in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to remove the spaces and newlines in the output, but need the spaces that are values in the dictionary.

code:

```
dict = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': ' '}
strg = 'abcd'
for i in strg:
    if i in dict:
       print (dict.get(i,)),
```

I get the following output:

```
1 2 3 space
```

what I want is:

```
123space
```

Comment: And what happens when something **isn't** in the lookup? eg: `strg = 'abcde'` ?

Comment: Don't print all lines, join as a single line then print.

Comment: `for i in strg:
 print dict.get(i),`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `dict.get` with a default value of an empty string with `str.join`:

```
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': ' '}
strg = 'abcd'
print("".join(d.get(i,"") for i in strg))
```

If you use repr you can see the space:

```
print(repr("".join(d.get(i,"") for i in strg)))
'123 '
```

Also avoid using dict as a variable name or something like`dict(foo="bar")` will not do what you think it will.

Comment: or `d.get(i, i)` depending if the original char should remain - hence my comment on the OP :)

Comment: @JonClements, yep. I think the OP should hopefully be able to adjust that part if needed ;)

Answer (score 4):

Along side the other answers that suggests `join` instead of using loops you can use `str.translate` for get the desire output :

```
>>> 'abcd'.translate(str.maketrans({'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': ' '}))
'123 '
```

And if you are in python 2 you can do the following :

```
>>> 'abcd'.translate(string.maketrans('abcd','123 '))
'123 '
```

or you can extract the input and out put for create your table, from dict :

```
>>> d={'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': ' '}
>>> inp=''.join(d.keys())
>>> out=''.join(d.values())
>>> 'abcd'.translate(string.maketrans(inp,out))
'123 '
```

Comment: This will keep the character in the string if it does not exist  in the dict, `'abcdz'.translate(str.maketrans({'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': ' '})) ->  '123 z`
 which may or may not be what the OP wants, it is also python3 specific

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sure that its like so! but for other string you need another `table` !!! how you change the string but not table??? its the philosophy of `str.translate` that you need a relevant table for your string based on your need!!!!!

Comment: The OP is using python2 so you need a python2 solution, I am familiar with how translate works.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I will add it too , but as OP used parenthesis for print i thought that he is using 3 !!!

Comment: if you look at the trailing comma and the output of the print you can see it is python2